# In AWS Amplify, is it possible to have two separate teams (repos) working on the frontend and backend exclusively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I would like to develop a React app using Amplify and two dev teams. Can one team work on the frontend exclusively, without giving them access to the backend code (the `amplify` folder)? The backend team can have access to both the backend and frontend code. If possible, how would I set it up?

Comment: I do not think this is possible unless you get really fancy with CDK.

Answer (score 3):

By following the instructions on [AWS Amplify's multiple frontends workflow page](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/teams/multi-frontend/#workflow), you could get this to work.

According to the docs,

> If you’re building a mobile and web app in separate repositories, the recommended workflow is to keep the backend definition (the amplify folder) in only one of the repositories and pull the metadata (the aws-exports.js or amplifyconfiguration.json file) in the second repository to connect to the same backend.

Therefore, you can keep the backend code in one of the reposities with a fake/demo frontend and then have the real/current frontend in a different folder with only `aws-exports.js` or `amplifyconfiguration.json`.